# How can I grant a non-Super User group permission to force check-in of articles?

Tags: joomla-3.x, acl, administration, configuration, check-in

I've created a custom user group for some Joomla 3.x websites which allow certain users particular administrative privileges, but only to the functionality they require (I trust my users', but I prefer fewer opportunities for exploits or accidental breakage).

One permission I need to grant them, is the ability to **check-in** articles that other users haven't correctly closed (where the padlock appears beside an article, preventing multiple users from editing the same item simultaneously). Currently, though, only Super Users are able to do this.

How can I give a custom user-group this click-on-the-padlock-to-kick-them-out functionality without granting them entire Super User privileges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have the latest Joomla version, if you are using the default usergroups available in Joomla, then the **administrators** usergroup should have access to the "**Check-In**" component.

The managers do not have access permissions by default. 
All you need to do, is to login as Super User, go to the Check-in component, click on Options and adjust the permissions settings for the component.

You will need to set the "**Access Administration Interface**" for the "**Managers**" group to "**Allowed**"

Also, for the current J3.4.3, the Check-In ACL settings require the Configure ACL & Options set to allowed, in order to fully unlock the check-in functionality for other User-Groups.

The same applies for any custom user-groups you might have.

[image: Global Configuration Screen for Check-in Component]

**Note:**
In older Joomla versions, there was a bug with the ACL for the check-in component, therefore a small hack was required to unlock it and assign permissions to other users than the Super User.

If by any chance it happens and you are in old Joomla versions where the bug existed, then you should update/upgrade your Joomla site the soonest possible, not only to have the bug fixed, but because apparently you run on outdated software.

Comment: Thanks very much for responding - and for providing such a clear and thorough answer.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have fully worked for me.

When making the change you describe, the padlock icon is now interactive, but when clicked, displays the message **"Check-in failed with the following error: The user checking in does not match the user who checked out the item."**

Do you know how I can allow the check-in to work for articles that aren't checked-out by other users?

(I have just tried this with both a custom group and the built-in Manager group).

Thanks again for any thoughts.

Comment: ... for articles that _are_ checked-out by other users, I should have said. (my 5 minute window to edit the comment expired, sorry - hopefully my message was clear enough anyway).

Comment: hmm yes- try adding also the Configure ACL & Options to Allowed for the Check-In component, and see if this way your issue is gone.

Comment: Yup - perfect - just did that just as you were commenting.  Worked perfectly.  You might want to add that to your answer, just so it's complete.

Either way, thank you ever so much - you've saved me a headache there, so I'm really grateful for your help.  -_^

Comment: You are welcome! - Answer Updated. I would expect only the initial ACL adjustment I proposed to be adequate to unlock the check-in functionality. It seems there is a bug or something, as the current condition makes no real sense.